# How can I reverse rows/cols of a matrix or reverse a vector with nalgebra?

Tags: rust, nalgebra

How can I `reverse` rows/cols of a matrix or a vector as this is possible in Eigen3?

How can I `reverseInPlace`?

See the Eigen3 docs, [quickref](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html) or [reverse](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a38ea394036d8b096abf322469c80198f)
, [reverseInPlace](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#adb8045155ea45f7961fc2a5170e1d921)
 for comparison:

> Vectors, rows, and/or columns of a matrix can be reversed (see DenseBase::reverse(), DenseBase::reverseInPlace(), VectorwiseOp::reverse()).

```cpp
vec.reverse()           mat.colwise().reverse()   mat.rowwise().reverse()
vec.reverseInPlace()
```